# How to use data validation to check/restrict condition between multiple columns from different sheets in Excel?

Tags: excel, validation

I'm trying to create a Excel file with some fill restrictions. This is a small example of a bigger data. Imagine I have two sheets in my excel file. The first one (Sheet 1) has two values (VALUE 1 and VALUE 2) for a specific TYPE and a specific ID, and it looks like this: [image]

And the second one (Sheet 2) also has the ID and TYPE columns, another one called YEAR and the last one (VALUE (SUM)) that must be the sum of VALUE 1 and VALUE 2 from Sheet 1 for the same type and id, counting all the years together. And it looks like this:

[image]

So for example in Sheet 1 for ID=22 and TYPE=A, the sum of VALUE 1 and VALUE 2 (1 + 2 = 3) must be the same as the sum of VALUE (SUM) for all the years containing the same ID and TYPE (22 and A, respectively) on Sheet 2. I would like to use data validation to raise an error in Sheet 2 if the sum of all values (for the same ID and TYPE) in Sheet 2 is different from VALUE 1 + VALUE 2.

In this case above, if I made a mistake and type a number in Sheet 2 that makes the sum different than 3, then it should raise an error. Anyone could help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a helper column to sheet 2 that displays the result of the check.

This is the formula in `E2`

```
=LET(
sumSheet1, SUM(FILTER('Sheet 1'!$C$2:$D$5,('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$5=A2)*('Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$5=B2))),
sumSheet2, SUM(FILTER($D$2:$D$12,($A$2:$A$12=A2)*($B$2:$B$12=B2))),
IF(sumSheet1 = sumSheet2,"OK","Total for ID = " & A2 & " and Type = " & B2 & " has to be " & sumSheet1 & " but equals to " & sumSheet2)
)
```

[image]

You could also use data validation with a userdefined formula based on the one above - set as warning.

```
=LET(
sumSheet1, SUM(FILTER('Sheet 1'!$C$2:$D$5,('Sheet 1'!$A$2:$A$5=A2)*('Sheet 1'!$B$2:$B$5=B2))),
sumSheet2, SUM(FILTER($D$2:$D$12,($A$2:$A$12=A2)*($B$2:$B$12=B2))),
sumSheet1 = sumSheet2)
)
```

But then the user has no information about the two sums ... to adjust the values.